# Simulating Zoom in Chrome with Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to do a test that involves browser zooming in Selenium (Java). The following was my approach:

```
WebElement html = m_webDriver.findElement(By.tagName("html"));
html.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD));
```

This worked fine in IE, but causes an exception in Chrome saying "cannot focus element", which happens whenever I attempt to send any keys in Chrome.

The following sources have also had similar issues, but no workaround listed works for me:

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2023/webdriver-api-failed-to-send-keys-because-cannot-focus-element-better-work

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2328&noredir=1

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but it is probably best to use JavaScript for that.

Something along the lines of:

```
driver.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom=1.0"); // or 0.9 or whatever
```